# Do React Hooks significantly improve the performance of mobile apps in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

Do the introduction of React hooks over the conventional class based code structure significantly improve the performance of the mobile apps in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say performance was ever a major impetus in react moving towards hooks. From what I understand the Powers That Be at Facebook/React have concluded that normal class-based components with their lifecycle methods cause more confusion than not which leads to poorer code quality (and thus maybe worse performance). Here is some of the [motivation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation) behind the push for hooks. Hooks allow you to write more concise and easier to read and reason about code.